# wso2 carbon studio: deploy and use custom mediator in ESB

Tags: mediator, wso2-esb

**how to deploy custom mediator to ESB and use it by UI**

I created a custom mediator and it's JAR file. Then created a carbon application project and selected a custom mediator artifact, after that exported CAR file of it.

Now I don't know where to locate the CAR file so that I can use my custom mediator in ESB (management console).

Another question is that, how can I use my mediator same first class mediator by UI (in management console)?

I created mediator using WSO2 developer studio 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Q1. Now I don't know where to locate the CAR file so that I can use my custom mediator in ESB (management console)?

Ans: If you are using Management console to deploy the CAR file, then you need to use "Add" button  under "Carbon Application" section on the Main tab of the ESB management console. Then you will be able to upload your CAR file from it and after couple of minutes you can try to create a Proxy service which uses that class mediator.

If you are using file system deploy the CAR file, in ESB 4.6.0 you need to deploy this CAR file to `<ESB_HOME>/repository/carbonapps/0` folder.

Q2. how can I use my mediator same first class mediator by UI?

Ans: In the proxy service creation inside In sequence or out sequence, you can use Class mediator and provide the fully qualified name of the class mediator you deployed with CAR file. You can try to use "Load Class" button there to see whether class mediator is actually  available in the server by that time.

Hope this answers your queries.

/Harshana